# Python subprocess.check_call Not Waiting Until Call Is Finished

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am running python 3.8 (required version for my application and in a virtual environment) with multiprocessing.pool package threadpool on Windows 10 Powershell.

When I am parallel computing, I can use subprocess.check_call on an executable function, say

```
proc = subprocess.check_call('sample.exe', cwd='<exe_directly>'),
```

and the thread process waits to proceed until the check_call it's finished.

However, when I use check_call on a Python call with arguments,
say

```
arg=['python','something.py','--arg','5']
Proc = subprocess.check_call(args)
```

The process does not wait

I tried to use other versions functions under subprocess (popen, call, run, etc).  However some would run but not wait, and others would give an exception error.

Ultimately, I was forced to use os.system

Could the subprocess.check_call not waiting be due to the python script that is being called launching a new python instance and the new PID is not tracked, causing the original python script to continue because the call returned that the PID of the launch is finished (not actual PID attached to the newly running script)?

Unfortunately, I am unable to paste code.

Comment: > *I tried to use other versions functions under subprocess (popen, call, run, etc). However some would run but not wait, and others would give an exception error.*
Which ones worked and which ones didn't? What was the error? Also, I understand that you cannot provide your current script, but check if another script that you can provide would cause the same problem.